# Fastly Issue with non-cacheable Blocks

Tags: magento2

We have a block for recently viewed products in magento 2.2.5 with custom attributes.

```
<block class="Magento\Reports\Block\Product\Widget\Viewed" after="-" name="recently_viewed" cacheable="false" template="Kinex_ProductWidget::product/recently_viewed.phtml">
            <action method="setPageSize">
                <argument name="page_size" xsi:type="number">15</argument>
            </action>
```

To make functional, we made this block non-cacheable as cacheable="false", which in turn make the full page non-cacheable. Due to this, Fastly caching conflicts with this page. Please suggest.

Comment: "which in turn make the full page non-cacheable" this is wrong. declaring a block as not cachable does not disable your FPC

Comment: cacheable=false on a block makes whole page not cacheable.

Comment: yes that is true and intended. https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/cache/page-caching.html